# What is the missing number in the question mark?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

What is the missing number in the question mark?
(My own puzzle)

> $(4, 3, 2),(4, 4, 4),(7, 9, 3),(8, 8, 4),(4, 12, 2),( 5, ?, 10)$

A) $1$
B) $3$
C) $5$
D) $10$
E) $66$
F) $14$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My Answer:

> **The answer is 10.**

Logic:

> Arithmetic progression of the units after; (Product of any two numbers out of three) + Remaining number.

Interpretation:

> 1. (3*2) +4= 10
>  2. (4*4) +4= 20
>  3. (7*3) +9= 30
>  4. (8*4) +8= 40
>  5. (12*4)+2= 50

Now the required answer,

> 5*10+X = 60
>  X = 10

Comment: Congratulations, that is the right answer.